# VBA Excel: How to use a named range in a combined Max, Index, Right statement

Tags: excel, vba

In a list with numbers of 7 characters I want to find the highest number of the last 3 numbers.
When I use the code below (found on this forum) and specify the Range like E2:E7 the code works.
I have dynamic ranges that are stored in a variable that I like to use.
When I put the range variable name at the *Range* location in the code below the code does not work anymore.

LastSerialIndex = [max(index(right(*Range*, 3)*1,))]

An answer like ("E2:E" & lRow) will do as well.

Comment: I hope you're using a different name for your range of cells than `Range`.

Comment: Yes it has a different name. Any suggestions what I can do?